# How can I count all of the lines in all of the files in the current directory and child directories?

Tags: ubuntu, wc, line-count

I'm trying to figure out how many lines of code have been written for an app. Code is in the current directory and child directories. I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name \*.c -exec wc -l {} \;  > /tmp/c_counts
find . -type f -name \*.h -exec wc -l {} \;  > /tmp/h_counts
```

This will produce the wc output for each file with a particular extension, one extension
per /tmp file.  You could run these results through a simple awk script to get the grand total, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the total lines you can use the following command:

`find . -name \*.c -o -name \*.h -exec cat {} \; | wc -l`